# What is the convention for log notation in biology?

Tags: physiology, zoology, marine-biology, allometry

I'm reading through some oldish (1980s) papers on length-weight relationships in fish and crustaceans. Many report log-log relationships without specifying whether this is natural log, base 10, etc. In mathematics log is typically assumed to mean natural log, but the results reported in these papers make more sense if you assume "log" means "log base 10".

Is there a convention in biology that I should be aware of?

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need any assistance with the site, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I typically use log10 for doing things like dose-response curves, but something like fold-induction of genes may be better expressed by log2. It would probably be safe to assume log10 if they don't specify, but for your own work you should definitely specify which base you're using. I can't recall ever seeing the natural log (base *e*) in biological papers, but that may just be my fields of interest, which aren't terribly mathematically-heavy.

Answer (score 8):

There is a reason for prevalent usage of log<sub>2</sub> and log<sub>10</sub> compared to log<sub>e</sub> in biology and other experimental sciences. Usually while doing measurements we are generally interested in fold changes and we generally talk in the sense of two-fold (or multiples of two) or ten-fold.

Doubling is a common phenomenon at least in case of growth and so a two-fold change would represent an event of doubling. log<sub>2</sub> gives you the extent of "doubling". Even in computer systems memory is always in the exponents of two (because of binary); so even there log<sub>2</sub> would make sense.

In biology you would generally not see a ten-fold change but in physics it is relatively common. Most values are represented in scientific notation which basically uses an exponent of 10. Also the metric units are in multiples of 10. Here log<sub>10</sub> would be more suitable.

log<sub>e</sub> has a special mathematical importance i.e. it can be denoted as a series. The euler's number has other important properties too. Therefore in most theoretical studies, both in biology and physics, log<sub>e</sub> is preferred because it makes more mathematical sense.

To sum up, experimentalists prefer log<sub>2</sub> or log<sub>10</sub> because they are better for representing measurements whereas theoreticians prefer log<sub>e</sub> because of its mathematical importance.

W.r.t the old paper that reports log-log relationships, the base of the logarithm wouldn't make any difference to the slope. But most likely it must be log<sub>10</sub> (I think back then log<sub>10</sub> was the default log; log<sub>2</sub> would be much more suitable for lengths and weights of organisms compared to log<sub>10</sub> because these measures would not vary in multiples of 10).

Comment: i'd say that there is no special "mathematical importance" in $log_e=ln$, it is just _cleaner_. If $x=e^t$, then $ln(x)=t$, without any hanging constants of conversion $log_e\rightarrow log_{10}$. In experiment it makes more sense to measure change in 2 or 10 times, than 2.71

Comment: @aandreev well it is easy when you are writing functions to describe a system. you can always convert the scales but when you are writing equations then `ln` is a direct result of some equations such as $\int \frac{dx}{x}$